# Initiate chat in dialogflow chatbot integrated in Skype?

Tags: skype, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have created a chatbot using dialogflow, then integrated it in Skype. Since there is no way to use Dialogflow to push notifications/send proactive messages, is this a way to make my chatbot send messages (notifications) to a specific user in response to a specific event?